# a:active isn't working, is there another code?

Tags: css, hyperlink, colors

Not sure if this is the css I am looking for.  I want the active link to have a hover color.  By active link I mean my aside link that I am currently visiting.

```css
.widget-area .widget a {
    color: #bc7ed1;
}
.widget-area .widget a:hover {
    color: #D6A0DB;
}
.widget-area .widget a:visited {
    color: #ccc2d3;
}
.widget-area .widget a:visited:hover {
    color: #;
}
.widget-area .widget a:active {
    color: #;
}
```

a:active isn't making a color change - is there a different word for the page I am currently visiting or active on?  Perhaps something like a:visited:active?  Just want the page I am on, that link to be a new color.

Comment: You don't have a color set for `a:active`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the pseudo class `:active`

`:active` is used for when a user clicks on the link and holds it. And `:visited` is when a url is already visited. [w3schools link on :active](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp)

If you need a special style for link of current page add a class like .currentpage to the a-tag with the url via backend or via javascript with style as

```
.currentpage {color:#ff0000;} /* or any color you prefer */
```

Hope this helps.